# Allow access to git repository from a certain commit

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a private project on github that I've decided to make public.

To test the project I used my graphical assets that I'd like to keep private. They are not present in the latest commit, but they are available on older commits.

Can I configure github (or use some git feature) to forbid access all previous commits without re-uploading the whole thing as a new project?

Comment: Should your question title be "Allow access to only certain commits" on github ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has published a [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) for pretty much exactly this scenario.

Comment: Thank you sir, I could not ask for a better answer. I wonder how my google search didn't give me this page.

Comment: @Amadan Really it was an interesting article..+1

Comment: Glad it helped. Please note the bit where it says that nothing is erased from GitHub, it is only made inaccessible unless you know the commit hash. It is enough for most purposes, but for real security where it *matters*, you will have to delete your GitHub repo and reupload your filtered repo.

Answer (score 1):

One of the alternatives may be using `Git Rebase`. But then even you won't be able to access your previous commits. If you are fine with that you can go like this

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

It will open a interactive editor. And you can selectively pick or squash your commits.

Read more about [Interactive Rebase here](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase)